# Problems linking a bootstrap button to a webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I am trying to link a button to a web page. This is the code that I have but when I click the button it doesn't direct to that page.

```
<button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"type="button" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown"
<a href= "HomePage.html">    
  Home Page ▼ </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You've a typo, you're missing `>` at the end of `button` tag :

```
<button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle".....toggle="dropdown">
_____________________________________________________________________________^
```

Hope this helps.

```html
<button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown">
<a href= "HomePage.html">    
Home Page ▼ </a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because you forgot to close the button tag

```
<button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"type="button" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown" <!-- ?? Where is your ">" ??-->
```

Try this:

```
<button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle"type="button" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <a href= "HomePage.html">Home Page</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is **NOT** related to the typo on `<button>`. I have tested your code and it does not work, indeed. In fact, your button wraps your link, so when you click the button, the default click event is not triggered on your `<a>` element. If you want to keep this HTML structure, you can use JavaScript to make it work:

```js
document.getElementById('WebPast').addEventListener('click', handler, true);

function handler(e) {
  location.href = e.target.children[0].href;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown">
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Home Page ▼</a>
  </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Button **are not** links

You can use just a `<a>` instead

```
<a href="HomePage.html" class="btn2 btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" id="WebPast" data-toggle="dropdown">Home Page ▼</a>
```

Works as well :)